# Function returns lots of notices

Tags: php, string, function, parameters, var

First off, my skill level is at best, a hobbit - i am a new compared to most if not all of you.

I am attempting to craft a function that will return a single `<br />` if no parameter/value is given, else will return as many `<br />` tags as the value `$num` is equal to.

I'm trying to create this function to:

**A)** Learn how to create functions

**B)** I hate typing the `<br />`

**C)** it's the idea for a function i came up with that interested me.

So, ideally, in my code, if type `getBrT()`, it will return one single `<br />` tag, if i type `getBrT(1)`, it also will return one single `<br />` tag, but if type `getBrT(5)`, it will return five `<br />` tags.

Its not working as i hoped when i type `getBrT()`. Do i always have to slug a value in? Is what I am trying to do not possible within the constraints of PHP?

Here is the function as I've built it:

```
function getBrT2($num){
    //if num equals 'nothing', 1 break - easier to call/type in code repeatedly
    if ($num = ''){
        echo '<br /';
    }else{
        //if num equals 'something', breaks equal value
        $i = 0; // initialize counter
        while ($i < $num) {
            echo '<br />'; // increment the counter
            $i++;}
        }           
    }
```

Comment: Consider using proper HTML and CSS where Line breaks are reduced to minimum. Then you won't need to type `<br /><br />< br/>`...

Comment: `if ($num = '')` does _not_ check for equality, it evaluates the resulting value of an assignment, in this case: assigning an empty string to `$num`, which is false. `$num`, then, will **always** be an empty string, and your function will _always_ loop with `$i < ''` as a condition, which makes no sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make sure this works when no value is passed to the function set a default value.

```
function getBrT2($num = 1) {             // default value is 1
    $num = (int) $num;                   // cast num to integer
    if ($num < 1) {                      // if num is 0 or negative make it 1
        $num = 1;  
    }
    return str_repeat('<br/>', $num);    // echo out as many <br/> as requested
}
echo getBrT2(1);       // prints out "<br/>"
echo getBrT2(5);       // prints out "<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>"
echo getBrT2();        // prints out "<br/>"
echo getBrT2('');      // prints out "<br/>"
echo getBrT2('hello'); // prints out "<br/>"
```

I made a few improvements to your function.

- Besides the default value I cast the value passed to an integer since that's what we need to work with. Any string values that do not begin with a number will be converted to `0`.
- Then we check if `$num` is `0` or a negative number. If so, we make it `1`.
- Then we use `str_repeat()` to create out as many `<br/>` tags as desired.
- Then we return that string so it can be echo'd out.

Comment: I feel function should return the value instead of print/echo

Comment: I agree but since this is how they're using it... Of course, they can modify this as necessary. The basic concept I am trying to illustrate remains the same.

Comment: So, if i'm understanding how you have restructured the function, you nullify the warning by loading a default value of '0' in the parens, which if it equals exactly '0' will return 'one' break, but if it is equal too two or more it will return as many br tags as equal to the value given so long as it is two or more. Am I understanding that correctly.

Comment: @RamSharma I went ahead and changed it since I made a bunch of other improvements as well. Might as well take it all the way.

Comment: Also - i never knew or would have imaged that str_repeat exists. This is like a godsend of eyeopening knowledge John if i'm understanding this all correctly (Thank you)

Comment: @Chezshire You're almost correct. It will return as many br tags as equal to the value given so long as it is *one* or more.

Comment: Perhaps `if ($num < 1) $num = 1;`, to avoid `str_repeat('str', -123);`

Comment: @JohnConde Don't mind but when I post above comment that time your function was echoing the value

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem Excellent tip. Code modified accordingly.

Comment: Thats what i meant to say (my english is not good); Super thank you for this bit of edjumacating, seriously eye opening to how i could have structured this function. This is great stuff.

Comment: Why would i want to return this vs. echoing it? Why do you feel that returning is better Ram Sharma?

Comment: @Chezshire: Because it is! Functions return, they should not control the output or flow of the entire application. The function doesn't know when or where it is called, if it echoes, you can't set cookies or start sessions after the call. If it returns, assign the string to a var, set your cookie and _then_ echo.

Comment: Thank you for all the help and answers - best question i've asked all year.

Comment: I was testing this, and as the solution appears now, changing 'if ($num === 0){' too 'if ($num < 1){' appears to break it so that no return is returned.